# AWS data pipeline activity with multiple inputs

Tags: variables, amazon-web-services, input, hive, amazon-data-pipeline

As part of an Amazon AWS data pipeline, I have a hive activity using two unstaged S3 data nodes as input.  What I want is to be able to set two script variables on the activity, each pointing to an input data node, but I can't get the syntax right.  With the single input, I could write the following and it would work just fine:

```
INPUT_FOO=#{input.directoryPath}
```

When I add the second input, I run into a problem of how to reference them since they are now an array of inputs, as you can see in the pipeline definition below.  Essentially, I want to achieve the following, but can't figure out the correct syntax:

```
INPUT_FOO=#{input[1].directoryPath}
INPUT_BAR=#{input[2].directoryPath}
```

Here's the activity portion of the pipeline definition:

```
{
  "id": "ActivityId_7u1sR",
  "input": [
    {
      "ref": "DataNodeId_iYnxf"
    },
    {
      "ref": "DataNodeId_162Ka"
    }
  ],
  "schedule": {
    "ref": "DefaultSchedule"
  },
  "scriptUri": "#{myS3ScriptLocation}calculate-results.q",
  "name": "Perform Calculations",
  "runsOn": {
    "ref": "EmrClusterId_jHeiV"
  },
  "scriptVariable": [
    "INPUT_SOURCE1=#{input[1].directoryPath}",
    "OUTPUT=#{output.directoryPath}Results/",
    "INPUT_SOURCE2=#{input[2].directoryPath}"
  ],
  "output": {
    "ref": "DataNodeId_2jY6v"
  },
  "type": "HiveActivity",
  "stage": "false"
}
```

I plan to keep the tables unstaged and take care of table creation in the hive script so that it's easier to run each Hive activity in isolation as well as in the pipeline itself.

Here's the error I see when using array syntax:

```
Unable to resolve input[1].directoryPath for object ActivityId_7u1sR'
```

Comment: Could the correct syntax be `input.directoryPath[1]`? I'm not sure what a `.q` file is. I think it might depend on how you index in that language

Comment: I tried the indexing on the directoryPath level, but the architect editor flagged it as an error, so it's not clear to me how indexing syntax works in a data pipeline variable, if it's possible.  Also, the q file is a Hive script.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand what you're trying to do now. Why don't or can't you just add the two sources as direct inputs to the HiveActivity? EDIT: If the 2 data sources are on S3, you should just explicitly type out their directories into the variable as well

Comment: This was not supported by Data Pipeline. But I think DataPipeline recently added support for expression evaluation on arrays. You might want to contact the team/forums-shout-out to add this to their docs. Meanwhile, try to use 'INPUT_SOURCE = input.directoryPath' and it probably passes you the data  as an array. And then parse it in your script. Sorry about a lot of handwaving.

Comment: I contacted AWS support, who contacted the data pipeline service team, and they said that this scenario is not currently supported, but that they added a feature request for it.  Thanks for all of the input on this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it stands now, this scenario is not supported, but a feature request was added to support it in the future.

Comment: Any status on this feature has it been added and is it available now?

Comment: Looks like AWS hasn't resolved this issue yet. We need to have some turn arounds to achieve it.